# How can I create a shared git repository starting from an initial git repository

Tags: git, repository

I currently have a project with a git repository. I would like to create a shared repository at another location. I had thought the approach I should take would be to first create a bare git repository and then clone my existing repository to it, but this did not work:

```
me@computer> git init --bare shared.git  #Create shared repository in new location
me@computer> git clone .git /path/to/shared/repository/shared.git #From dir with existing repository, try to create clone in shared repository

fatal: destination path '/path/to/shared/repository/shared.git' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

I decided next to clone the shared git repository, add all the files from my existing project to the directory with the new repository, next add and commit those files to the new repository and then use `git push` to place all these files in the shared repository. This, too, did not work. The error I got was:

```
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to '/path/to/shared/repository/shared.git'
```

How can I take the files in my existing repository and put them in a shared repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new empty git repository (e.g., say named `shared.git`) as you would normally create.

Clone your existing repository into a dir named `shared`:

```
$ git clone url_to_existing.git shared
```

Then change the remote of your repository to make `origin` point to the new create repository (`URL_OF_SHARED_GIT` is the URL of the `shared.git` repository):

```
$ cd shared
$ git remote set-url origin URL_OF_SHARED_GIT
```

Then push master branch:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

You are done!

Note that it will only push the master branch. If you want to push other branches, you have to do it the same for the other branches. To push tags use `git push --tags`. Now if you clone `shared.git` it will reflect what you pushed.

Comment: Definitely correct, but I think there are some unnecessary steps. When you clone a repo, the origin should automatically be set as a remote in your clone. Try `git remote -v` to check that. And master already exists in the origin, so the `-u` isn't needed when pushing. It is needed, however, if you're pushing a new branch that only exists locally. +1 for this answer, though, as it's more informative than mine.

Comment: *the origin should automatically be set as a remote in your clone*: here `git clone` is done on `existing.git` so `origin` is set to the remote of `existing.git`, the `git remote set-url` is performed to change the remote from `existing.git` remote to `shared.git` remote.

Comment: Right. If the OP wants to push an existing Git clone to a different remote, then your steps are needed. I was just providing a fix for the last attempt mentioned by the OP. The empty repo was cloned, the files moved into the clone, add and committed, and then `git push` failed because a branch was not specified. OP should accept your answer as it's a clear end-to-end solution to the problem. I'm just going to delete mine.

Comment: @ouah - Thanks. I will try this will try this tomorrow and let you know

Comment: Here is another good explanation: http://thelucid.com/2008/12/02/git-setting-up-a-remote-repository-and-doing-an-initial-push/